# Angular CLI /Webpack - ERROR in scripts.<HASH>.js from Terser undefined

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I'm getting this error from the Terser plugin when doing a production build with Angular CLI. I am trying to find more information about whats going wrong, but I do not know how/where to look for some hints about the root cause.

I am running with the --verbose flag but it still just give me this very unspecific error. Any ideas?

`ERROR in scripts.<HASH>.js from Terser undefined`

Version (have tried different node versions)

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.2
@angular/cli                      7.0.2
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.19
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.2
@schematics/angular               7.0.2
@schematics/update                0.10.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.3
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the tether npm package by any chance?

I had the same problem, then I removed the tether package as per this issue, and the --prod build is now working for me.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12662

Don't forget to remove tether.js from you angular.json scripts section if its there.